# Confusion in configuration of SonarQube with PostgreSQL DB

Tags: sonarqube

I have SonarQube 5.6 version installed and RDS PostgreSQL DB connected to it on AWS. I have this setup since a long time and many projects run on every day schedule on SonarQube. Not getting any issue or errors there. but looks like my Database configuration is not correct. because when i looked into Database. I don't see much more movement or anything stored there. I have updated conf/sonar.properties files with database endpoint and credentials. It looks like it's connected. How to make sure this? like, my database is getting used by sonarqube?

Because sonarQube documentation is saying, No database required after 5.2 version.

can someone please explain me architecture, What is right way to setup this?

I am getting an error as follow,

INFO web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql:sonarprod.cyfa9ycgfky0.us-east-1.rds.amazona‌​ws.com 2017.02.24 19:54:03 
ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').

I have checked everything is correct in connection string, username, password. all looks correct to me. I have specific ports open for communication. what does this error means? what am i missing?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You are looking for [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Architecture+and+Integration)?

Answer (score 0):

You can see which database is used by SonarQube by having a look at server's log.
For instance, here's the entry you'll find when PostgreSQL is used :

> 2017.02.15 16:46:39 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sonar

Comment: i checked that. I am getting errors as follow, INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:postgresql:sonarprod.cyfa9ycgfky0.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
2017.02.24 19:54:03 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not connect to database. Please check connectivity and settings (see the properties prefixed by 'sonar.jdbc.').

Comment: It means the configuration you're using is wrong : you should check that you can access to the DB with these settings

Comment: Got it. I was not passing DB name in configuration. Thank you for help.